# Python: how to get only positive numbers of nested int list with resonable performance

Tags: python, performance, list

My code is possibly slow:

```
onlyPositives = map ( (lambda mylist: [elem for elem in mylist if elem > 0]) , myintlist )
```

what is a fast way to do that?
(For 1 million sub lists of size 50 ints).

Comment: Without knowing your actual problem, it's a little hard to say.  But, I will say that depending on your problem, it might be worth looking into `numpy` (and friends).  They can speed up computations like this a decent amount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the function separately instead of using a `lambda` and use a list comprehension instead of `map()`:

```
def func(mylist):
    return [elem for elem in mylist if elem > 0]

onlyPositives = [func(e) for e in myintlist]
```

Based on the comments below I think it's worth profiling various versions of this code, including `map()`, `filter()` and generator expressions to see what's fastest.

However with one million sublists there's only so much you can do.

Comment: If you're looking to squeeze out the last bit of performance, you probably want to define that helper `func` globally, but then bind it to a local variable inside this function. But otherwise, yeah, this is about it.

Comment: Note that the page is based on Python as of 1996, possibly with a few changes since then. I wouldn't trust it very far. Anyway, it's more important to show the alternatives (as you did) so the OP can test them on his own data than to try to guess which will turn out to be faster.

Comment: @abarnert: Yeah, I removed it again; the page also says list comphrension is faster than `map()` so I'll go by that (https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips)

Comment: You might want to use generator comprehension instead of list comprehension. :)

Comment: Based on my experience, `map` + non-lambda function is *usually* slightly faster than a list-comprehension (but not always).  However, that would be a 5% max difference -- It's really not worth a whole lot in the outer loop, and the inner loop doesn't translate nicely to a `map`, so I'm not sure it's really worth squabbling over :)

Comment: The reason `map` wins in CPython is that `map` only resolves the name `func` once, while the listcomp has to resolve it for every element in `myintlist` *and* because the loop internals all run "at C speed" (the listcomp does the loop in bytecode - many more trips around the eval loop).

Comment: @PauloFreitas: I'd have to measure that; the end result needs to be list of lists anyway.

Comment: Might be worth trying `filter((0.).__lt__, sub_list)` to see if that has any performance benefits... (I don't like the `float`, but `int`s don't have a `__lt__`/other comparison method....

Comment: @JonClements: IIRC, int has an old-fashioned `__cmp__` method instead (and that was fixed in 3.x when `__cmp__` was scrapped). But then to use that, you'd need to compare the result of `__cmp__`, which is kind of pointless…

Answer (score 2):

First, I'll assume your data structure and your algorithm can't be improved.

In that case, there's nothing wrong with your implementation of your algorithm. As Simeon Visser points out, there may be ways to lower the overhead a tiny bit, but there's only so much you can accomplish there.

But if you're willing to look beyond speeding up the Python, there are three big options:

- Parallelize the code. Run four processes, and have each one transform a quarter of the original list. It should be nearly 4x as fast.
- Vectorize the code, using something like NumPy and/or Pandas. When you're doing simple arithmetic (like > 0), the Python looping overhead can easily be 10x slower than the actual work, so this can give you a 10x speedup. (Needless to say, this is cheating—I assumed your data structure couldn't be changed, and then I changed it. But if the transformation is a trivial and obvious one—e.g., from a fixed-shape 2D array represented as a list of lists to a fixed-shape 2D array represented as an `ndarray`, it's worth cheating.)
- Compile the code, whether by writing it in Cython instead of Python, or by running it in PyPy instead of CPython. Generally this gives you a bit less speedup than NumPy (and the speedup is even more unpredictable in advance), but it's also a lot less work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of ways - the first one is the one you provided.  BTW, function calls have relatively significant overhead in CPython.  For speed, you might do well to use pypy, numba or cython.  lambda and def will slow things down if you want to stay with unadorned CPython.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

myintlist = [ [ 1, 2, 3, -1, -6, 0 ], [ 5, 6, 7, -4, 2, -6, 3, -6, 0, 10] ]
onlyPositives = map ((lambda mylist: [ elem for elem in mylist if elem > 0 ]), myintlist)
print(onlyPositives)

onlyPositives2 = []
for input_sublist in myintlist:
    output_sublist = (element for element in input_sublist if element > 0)
    onlyPositives2.append(output_sublist)
print(onlyPositives2)

# You could change the list comprehension to another generator expression if you want
onlyPositives3 = ([element for element in input_sublist if element > 0] for input_sublist in myintlist)
print(onlyPositives3)
```

Comment: Replacing his list of lists with a list of generators doesn't seem like a good idea, unless he doesn't actually need to evaluate all of the elements of each one.