# Quickly check if a list is a sublist, of one of the elements of a nested list

Tags: python, performance, list

As a result of a SAT solver, I have a big nested int list of the models of a logic formular.
The list has one million sublists of approxomatly length 30.

Example data:

```
[[-1, -2, 3, -4, -5, 6, 7, -8, -9, -10, -11, -12, 13, 14, 15, -16, 17, -18, -19, -20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, -26, -27, 28, 29, 30, -31, 32, 33, -34, 35, 36, -37], [-1, -2, 3, -4, -5, 6, 7, -8, -9, -10, -11, -12, 13, 14, 15, -16, 17, -18, -19, -20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, -26, -27, 28, 29, 30, -31, 32, 33, -34, 35, 36, 37], [-1, -2, 3, -4, -5, 6, 7, -8, -9, -10, -11, -12, 13, 14, 15, -16, 17, -18, -19, -20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, -26, -27, 28, 29, 30, -31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, -37], [-1, -2, 3, -4, -5, 6, 7, -8, -9, -10, -11, -12, 13, 14, 15, -16, 17, -18, -19, -20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, -26, -27, 28, 29, 30, -31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37], [-1, -2, 3, -4, -5, 6, 7, -8, -9, -10, -11, -12, 13, 14, 15, -16, 17, -18, -19, -20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, -26, -27, 28, 29, 30, -31, 32, 33, 34, -35, 36, -37], [-1, -2, 3, -4, -5, 6, 7, -8, -9, -10, -11, -12, 13, 14, 15, -16, 17, -18, -19, -20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, -26, -27, 28, 29, 30, -31, 32, 33, 34, -35, 36, 37], [-1, -2, 3, -4, -5, 6, 7, -8, -9, -10, -11, -12, 13, 14, 15, -16, 17, -18, -19, -20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, -26, -27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, -35, 36, -37], [-1, -2, 3, -4, -5, 6, 7, -8, -9, -10, -11, -12, 13, 14, 15, -16, 17, -18, -19, -20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, -26, -27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, -35, 36, 37]]
```

I need to check if a list, say [4,5,6] consists of elements that are part of one of the nests lists.

say my list is:

```
[ [5,12,46,4,99,6],[23,66,99,32,77] ]
```

If I run my program with

```
[4,5,6]
```

It should return `true`

As I need to perform the test 500 times with different lists, the problem is performance critical, I guess.

Here is my plan:

- sort the list to check
- sort the big nested list
- compare always the two smallest numbers first (say I search for 2 and the sublist start with 3, I can go on to the next sublist)

Or is there a better approach, e.g., by using a dict?

(PS: As I am looking only for positive numbers I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869737/python-how-to-get-only-positive-numbers-of-nested-int-list-with-resonable-perfo) before to get rid of all the negative numbers.)

Comment: As a first step, you should really use a Python `set` data structure, since membership is the criteria you need and not any ordering information. In particular, the `set.issubset` method might be an efficient enough implementation to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use sets:

```
>>> data = [ [5,12,46,4,99,6],[23,66,99,32,77] ]
>>> set_data = [set(s) for s in data]
>>> set_data
[set([99, 4, 5, 6, 12, 46]), set([32, 66, 99, 77, 23])]
>>> myset = set([4,5,6])
>>> [myset.issubset(s) for s in set_data]
[True, False]
```

Comment: I just need to stop after I found the first "True". Do I use a foreach loop then?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a list comprehension which needlessly creates a whole new list in memory, use a generator expression with any(). Using Visser's code as a starting point:

```
>>> data = [ [5,12,46,4,99,6],[23,66,99,32,77] ]
>>> set_data = [set(s) for s in data]
>>> set_data
[set([99, 4, 5, 6, 12, 46]), set([32, 66, 99, 77, 23])]
>>> myset = set([4,5,6])
>>> any(myset.issubset(s) for s in set_data)
True
```